# R: How should I create Grid-graphics?

Tags: r, plot, lattice, levelplot

> **Goal**
>
> [image]
>
> **Code**
>
> ```
> require(lattice)
>
> png('my_typing.png')
> par(mfrow=c(2,1))
>
> read.csv('race_data.csv')->sol
> plot(sol$Race.., sol$WPM*sol$Accuracy, type='l')
>
> # TODO: it wrongly substitutes the plot with levelplot
> # TODO: I want two plots one below another, plot and then levelplot below
> levelplot(cor(sol[1:5]))
> ```

**Helper questions**

> 1. How can I plot the normal plot and the special plot together in one PNG -file?
> 2. Should I combine different plotting -packages such as lattice and grid to base?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/index.html

Comment: I hope I did not change the question. By "grid grahpics", I mean stuff like in the picture. Beware the confusion, I do not mean just the things by the Grid -pkg. I am unsure whether I should I ask the question like `"How should I create grid-graphics?"` -- to make it sure that I am interested to find out also opnions for-and-against different approaches...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [gridBase](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/index.html) package which provides some support for combining grid and base graphics output.

Here is a simple example:

```
library("grid")
library("gridBase")
library("lattice")

# example from levelplot help page
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
g <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
g$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
p <- levelplot(z~x*y, g, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
               ylab="", main="lattice levelplot",
               colorkey=FALSE, region=TRUE)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(2, 1,
                                         heights=unit(c(2, 1), "null"))))
vp <- pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1))
par(omi=gridOMI())
# base graphics
plot(1:10, main="base graphics plot")
popViewport()
# lattice plot
vp <- pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2, layout.pos.col=1))
print(p, vp=vp, newpage=FALSE)
popViewport()
popViewport()
```

[image: gridBase example]

Comment: What is your opinion about mixing different syntaxes together to create Grid-graphics like the picture in q? MR discouraged it in #R and suggested to use consistenly one format.

Comment: I would also be consistent; I prefer `ggplot2` but  I also use `lattice` sometimes.

Comment: So you suggest me to use `ggplot2` for grid-graphics -generation? Comparison between ggplot2 and lattice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759556/r-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-lattice-versus-ggplot2). So for a newbie like me it is better to start learning the ggplot2 instead of playing with this combination -pkg and inconsistencies?

Comment: I did not fully understand: did you suggest not use gridBase? I cannot yet understand whether I can do all GridGraphics with ggplot2 without gridBase.

Answer (score 0):

MR. in #R recommened to use just one type of plot -things. Trellis -functions are not interchangeable with the base functions so one should also reprogram the syntax for things such as trend-line and titles. Otherwise, you create syntantic confusing over time and consistency to dogs.

*I am trying to find out alternative ways of doing Grid-graphics so the writing in progress.*

**Different ways of creating Grid-graphics**

> **1. Trellis -way of doing things, using lattice -pkg, code [here](http://pastie.org/4545982)**
>
> [image]
>
> **2. Combining different plot -pkgs**
>
> MR. discouraged this way but rcs's way of doing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021940/164148). According to MR, **grid is `"much more user friendly way of creating grid grapics"`**, so I think it is worth learning, and things such as lattice and ggplot2 are built on top of grid. Please, consult this paper about combining base -plotting-functions and the grid -plotting-functions [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf).