# R: pie chart with different type of information in colours and slices?

Tags: r, graphics, annotations, pie-chart, label

I am trying to make the below-style pie-chart in R. You can find the original Figure 1 on page 5, here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XgG.png). Anyway the below is obfuscated version, not to break any copyrights and only for educational purposes so fair usage.

[image]

What's the easiest way (package) to do this (the curly lines are labels with text for the sections)?

**Description**

> I need the colours to represent one factor of my data, and the slices - another. For example, the paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XgG.png) has different aspects of information in the colours and in the slices (but for sake of simplicity without the three rings that they've used to denote taxonomic levels).

**References**

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XgG.png) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283605003190#gr1

Comment: Which pie? Could you specify the page number? And it would be useful to see the picture without purchasing the paper. Your question is -- how can I label a pie-chart and something else?

Comment: @hhh In the pdf - page 5, Figure 1.And I'm afraid that I can't copy the figure here as it is under copyright, and I have NOT been able find a similar figure in an open-access journal. Figure 1 if viewed in the html. My question is how can I present two types of data in one pie chart - one using colour and one using lines? This is not labels and annotation. (see below)

Comment: Thank you, obfuscated the figure with some artistic slant and added it to the question. Now it is should be fine, hope someone can help you find the right pkg to do this -- I don't have just now time but will look later, hope the edit will help :)

Answer (score 3):

Start up `R` in terminal, type `?pie` and scroll down to examples. Which pie -chart would you like to have? For further studies, keywords may be annotations and labels.

**Suggestion 1**

> ```
> $ cat t.r 
> require(grDevices)
>
> pie.sales <- c(0.12, 0.3, 0.26, 0.16, 0.04, 0.12)
> png('t1.png')
>  pie(pie.sales, clockwise=TRUE, main="pie(*, clockwise=TRUE)", 
>      labels=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))
>  segments(0,0, 0,1, col= "red", lwd = 2)
>  text(0,1, "init.angle = 90", col= "red")
> ```
>
> $ Rscript t.r
>
> $ feh t1.png
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my query! I still argue that I am not looking for multiple ways of labelling - I am looking for a way to have the lines and colours to represent different aspects of my data. However, your answer has definitely pointed me in the right direction. Basically, I need to use the border=NA option (giving me the colours data layer), combined with a modification of segments (giving me the sectors data layer). Thank you :)

Comment: @darya not sure about the right direction. Some R -users zwitch to GRID -things such as ggplot2/lattice. This solution candidate is based on the base -tools that may not be the best way of doing things, in certain cases such as Grid-graphics, it may make sense to prefer non-basic packages unless hacking your thing. I am not expert in Grid -things so cannot comment which method is actually the best solution candidate here. More about Grid -graphics [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12021824/164148) or paper [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf).